# Getting an error "_kwargs = spec_.kwargs.copy()" saying "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'" when running tensor2tensor

Tags: transformer-model, piano, magenta, tensor2tensor, trax

I am currently trying to run [this](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/magenta/piano_transformer/piano_transformer.ipynb) google collab notebook. It is a notebook that creates a transformer model and takes input from piano performances and creates newly generated music. I am getting this error when I try importing the tensor2tensor modules.

ERROR ='NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

This notebook also somehow only runs on tensorflow v1, as opposed to the most current version.

I believe this has something to do with tensor2tensor currently being depreciated. I see there is a successor library called trax, but it does not have any of the models referenced in the notebook as of yet. Is it possible to migrate the code used in tensor2tensor to trax? I have never migrated github repositories before and any advice or information would be greatly appreciatred.

It seems like there are a million problems with this notebook, but it's such a good source of information that I don't want to give up on it.

Any guidance would be awesome. Thanks